# Python popen wont work with block devices

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I am wring a small forensic app which looks like this so far

```
import time, os,sys

def getter():
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    print "File Entered: " + filename
    os.system('file ' + filename)
    print "\n"
    pipe =  os.popen("xxd " + filename, "r")
    print pipe.read()
```

I input via the command line a file and it prints out the type of file and then it is supposed to create a pipe from the terminal back to the python app under the pipe name "pipe".  I then read the pipe named "pipe"

This works great on smaller text files, but it will not work on block devices even when I run this app as super user.  In the end this will recover files based on the output of xxd.

any tips, thank you.

Comment: `popen` is deprecated. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: Deprecated means there are now better ways to perform the same task, and the deprecated ways will be removed from the language at some point in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you just run `xxd /dev/diskwhatever` from the shell prompt?  Does it work, and how much information does it spew out?  Assuming that, as superuser, you do have read permission, the attempt to read everything at one gulp in your code's last line would be the point where failure could be expected (since the amount of information can be really huge); the workaround would be to read a little at a time, instead of doing a single `.read()` call.

**Edit**: whether you get your pipe in the nice modern way (with `subprocess`) or the deprecated-but-still-working old way (with `popen`), makes no difference to this problem.  In either case, you can get one line at a time by just looping over the pipe object, for example:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(whatever, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in child.stdout:
  print "One more line:", line
```

Comment: That's it. Try print pipe.read(1) and you might get some data.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you've tried the same command from the shell prompt and it worked well, even when piped to `less` or something of the sort.

I have a strong feeling that using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) will fix this behavior; This module replaces the `popen` call which is deprecated, and gives a great degree of flexibility in running and getting results from the executed commands.

```
output = Popen(["xxd", "file"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Try to run the process under its own shell, and read its pipe. If this still does not work, make sure to set a reasonable limit to its buffer size, and make sure you're not using `communicate` which will make you wait till the process terminates (a long time when handling a block device).

Comment my answer if it didn't work, and try to accurately describe what wen't wrong - is it freezing, just no output or corrupt results?

Comment: what can I use to pull the data one line at a time, instead of communicate?  this is what I have so far  "pipe =  subprocess.Popen(["xxd",filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)"

Comment: @Recursion, I just edited my answer to show that -- it boils down to doing `for line in pipe.stdout:`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably lies with how you call `xxd`, given that your application doesn't do anything at all with the file.

Comment: ...unless your problem is actually using the pipe object popen gives you.

Comment: when I run it in the terminal it works fine.  It also works fine for a small text file.